# How can i show the archives on side bar of the home page, Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site, and in the home page , there is side bar section.In this section i need to display the archives like

February 2010

- friday 5th
- friday 12th
- friday 19th
- friday 26th

March 2010

- friday 5th
- friday 12th
- friday 19th
- friday 26th

April2010

- friday 2th
- friday 9th
- friday 16th
- friday 23th
- friday 30th

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, unhappily, no quick and easy way to do this. You will need to create your own function for generating the archive display.

If I were you I'd find the wp_get_archives() function in the core and copy it into your functions.php file with your own function name, and hack around with it there to get the display the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks, i tried in the way you suggested and finally i got it.Once more thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is widget-ready, you can simply drop the **Archives** widget on your sidebar from the admin side.